# native library not found in instrumentation tests

Tags: android, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in my android instrumentation tests. It works fine on newer devices (gnex, nexus 5, nexus 7) but not on older ones (nexus one, samsung GT-P7500R). I'm using static initialization for this library (as opposed to using the manager app that pools/shares the native libs).

It's the same build code, based on gradle and including the same .so files, for both armeabi and armeabi-v7a.

I've installed OpenCVManager and another app using it and it works fine even on older devices. I peeked inside the apk and even copied the same .so files over but still getting the same error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:54)
at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:85)
at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:29)
at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:51)
```

Any ideas on what else could be different? I looked inside the instrumentation apk (debug test) and the lib files are there...

Edit: I tried various setups but none of them work:
 - just armeabi files in armeabi folder
 - just armeabi-v7a files in armeabi-v7a folder
 - just armeabi files in top folder (lib folder inside apk)
 - just armeabi-v7a files in top folder (lib folder inside apk)
 - manually loading opencv_java
 - manually loading OpenCVENgine, OpenCVEngine_jni ("borrowed" from the OpenCVManager app).

I've tried some of these approaches on other devices and they work fine...

Comment: Usually static
 {
  OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
 } is the resolution for me in that sense at the root of your application.  But doesn't seem to be by the way you are saying you load it.  Possibly some of the static libs are missing in your armeabi folder?

Comment: Interestingly on nexus one, the opencv manager comes only with an armeabi-v7a folder, and I tried bundling those in, but no luck.

Comment: Without the armeabi folder, you will not be able to use the opencv library on older devices.  I have a couple here in the office that are old and would not function with just a armeabi-v7 folder.  I have an armeabi folder structure in the OpenCV Android Library project that I had downloaded.  If you provide that folder in your application under the /libs folder in addition to your existing folder, you would most likely get back to linking on those older systems.

Comment: I do have both armeabi and armeabi-v7a as stated in the original question, and they contain the same files. I found some reports stating older devices might have issues loading files from one folder when the other is present, but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with the fact that the opencv library was part of the dependencies for the instrumentation test project.

Switching from `androidTestCompile` to `compile` in the `build.gradle` file (basically, adding the dependency to the app under test rather than the test app) makes the library load work properly. I'll dig some more to see if there are any workarounds.